# Solr Search like default search

Tags: apache, drupal, search, solr

Поставил `search_api` и `search_api_solr` плагины,настроил Solr, но вот как поставить теперь его как дефолтный, в `Configuration -> Search settings` не появляется возможность выбрать его, подскажите что не так? Сам поиск работает, создал вьюшку все индексирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`search_api` - самостоятельная поисковая система.

Выключите `search`, создайте блок во вьюшке с `exposed` фильтром поискового запроса и используйте его.